# T-SQL : calculate DateTime gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2016

Code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LookupDates ;

CREATE TABLE #LookupDates (StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #LookupDates
VALUES
    ( '2019-12-01 08:00:00', '2019-12-01 16:00:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-02 10:00:00', '2019-12-02 18:00:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-03 08:30:00', '2019-12-03 16:30:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-04 08:00:00', '2019-12-04 16:00:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-05 08:00:00', '2019-12-05 16:00:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-06 09:00:00', '2019-12-06 17:00:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-07 08:30:00', '2019-12-07 16:30:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-08 11:00:00', '2019-12-08 15:30:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-09 08:30:00', '2019-12-09 16:30:00' )
  , ( '2019-12-10 10:30:00', '2019-12-10 16:45:00' )

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Data ;

CREATE TABLE #Data (EmpId INT, ClockInDate DATETIME, ClockOutDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES
    ( 1, '2019-12-01 07:00:00', '2019-12-01 07:30:00' ) -- Completely before
  , ( 1, '2019-12-01 18:00:00', '2019-12-01 22:00:00' ) -- Completely after
  , ( 1, '2019-12-02 09:30:00', '2019-12-02 18:00:00' ) -- Clockin before
  , ( 1, '2019-12-03 09:00:00', '2019-12-03 16:30:00' ) -- Clockin after
  , ( 1, '2019-12-04 08:00:00', '2019-12-04 15:45:00' ) -- Clockout before
  , ( 1, '2019-12-05 08:00:00', '2019-12-05 17:15:00' ) -- Clockout after
  , ( 1, '2019-12-06 08:40:00', '2019-12-06 16:45:00' ) -- Clockin before & Clockout before
  , ( 1, '2019-12-07 08:25:00', '2019-12-07 17:05:00' ) -- Clockin before & Clockout after
  , ( 1, '2019-12-08 12:00:00', '2019-12-08 15:15:00' ) -- Clockin after & Clockout before
  , ( 1, '2019-12-09 08:30:01', '2019-12-09 16:30:27' ) -- Clockin after & Clockout before
  , ( 1, '2019-12-10 10:30:00', '2019-12-10 16:45:00' ) -- Clockin on-time & Clockout on-time
```

Desc:

`LookupDates` contains company's daily operating hours. Actual table has additional days worth of data.

Data contains each employee's ClockIn/Out timestamps. Actual table has additional emps' and days worth of data.

**Goal**: to find if an entry in #Data is off from that day's operating hours.

- Did the emp clockin early? By how many seconds?
- Did the emp clockin late? By how many seconds?
- Did the emp clockout early? By how many seconds?
- Did the emp clockout late? By how many seconds?

Desired output:

```
EmpId       LookupStartDate         ClockInDate             IsClockInBefore     ClockInBeforeTimeInSec      IsClockInAfter      ClockInAfterTimeInSec   LookupEndDate           ClockOutDate            IsClockOutBefore    ClockOutBeforeTimeInSec     IsClockOutAfter     ClockOutAfterTimeInSec
1           '2019-12-01 08:00:00'   '2019-12-01 07:00:00'   1                   3600                        0                   0                       '2019-12-01 16:00:00'   '2019-12-01 07:30:00'   1                   30600                       0                   0
1           '2019-12-01 08:00:00'   '2019-12-01 18:00:00'   0                   0                           1                   36000                   '2019-12-01 16:00:00'   '2019-12-01 22:00:00'   0                   0                           1                   21600
1           '2019-12-02 10:00:00'   '2019-12-02 09:30:00'   1                   1800                        0                   0                       '2019-12-02 18:00:00'   '2019-12-02 18:00:00'   0                   0                           0                   0
1           '2019-12-03 08:30:00'   '2019-12-03 09:00:00'   0                   0                           1                   1800                    '2019-12-03 16:30:00'   '2019-12-03 16:30:00'   0                   0                           0                   0
1           '2019-12-04 08:00:00'   '2019-12-04 08:00:00'   0                   0                           0                   0                       '2019-12-04 16:00:00'   '2019-12-04 15:45:00'   1                   900                         0                   0
1           '2019-12-05 08:00:00'   '2019-12-05 08:00:00'   0                   0                           0                   0                       '2019-12-05 16:00:00'   '2019-12-05 17:15:00'   0                   0                           1                   4500
1           '2019-12-06 09:00:00'   '2019-12-06 08:40:00'   1                   1200                        0                   0                       '2019-12-06 17:00:00'   '2019-12-06 16:45:00'   1                   900                         0                   0
1           '2019-12-07 08:30:00'   '2019-12-07 08:25:00'   1                   300                         0                   0                       '2019-12-07 16:30:00'   '2019-12-07 17:05:00'   0                   0                           1                   2100
1           '2019-12-08 11:00:00'   '2019-12-08 12:00:00'   0                   0                           1                   3600                    '2019-12-08 15:30:00'   '2019-12-08 15:15:00'   1                   900                         0                   0
1           '2019-12-09 08:30:00'   '2019-12-09 08:30:01'   0                   0                           1                   1                       '2019-12-09 16:30:00'   '2019-12-09 16:30:27'   0                   0                           1                   27
1           '2019-12-10 10:30:00'   '2019-12-10 10:30:00'   0                   0                           0                   0                       '2019-12-10 16:45:00'   '2019-12-10 16:45:00'   0                   0                           0                   0
```

Comment: So you simply join on the date portion only. E.g., a inner join b on cast(a.LookupStartDate as date) = cast(b.ClockInDate as date)? But I get the feeling that there might be more to this "problem" than what you describe.

Comment: Nice job setting up the data. Well done, and thanks. What's missing, though, is your attempt to solve the problem, and an indication of where you're having trouble. We're not here to write your code for you. We're here to help with problems you're having.

Comment: You've omitted what you tried and a question. It looks like you want to join on `date`, calculate the overlaps, if any, and then use `case` expressions to generate some `bit` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
     #Data.EmpId
    ,#LookupDates.StartDate as LookupStartDate
    ,#Data.ClockInDate
    ,case when #Data.ClockInDate < #LookupDates.StartDate then 1 else 0 end as IsClockInBefore
    ,case when #Data.ClockInDate < #LookupDates.StartDate then datediff(second, #Data.ClockInDate, #LookupDates.StartDate) else 0 end as ClockInBeforeTimeInSec
    ,case when #Data.ClockInDate > #LookupDates.StartDate then 1 else 0 end as IsClockInAfter
    ,case when #Data.ClockInDate > #LookupDates.StartDate then datediff(second, #LookupDates.StartDate, #Data.ClockInDate) else 0 end as ClockInAfterTimeInSec
    ,#LookupDates.EndDate as LookupEndDate
    ,#Data.ClockOutDate
    ,case when #Data.ClockOutDate < #LookupDates.EndDate then 1 else 0 end as IsClockOutBefore
    ,case when #Data.ClockOutDate < #LookupDates.EndDate then datediff(second, #Data.ClockOutDate, #LookupDates.EndDate) else 0 end as ClockOutBeforeTimeInSec
    ,case when #Data.ClockOutDate > #LookupDates.EndDate then 1 else 0 end as IsClockOutAfter
    ,case when #Data.ClockOutDate > #LookupDates.EndDate then datediff(second, #LookupDates.EndDate, #Data.ClockOutDate) else 0 end as ClockOutAfterTimeInSec
from
    #LookupDates
    inner join
    #Data on cast(#LookupDates.StartDate as date) = cast(#Data.ClockInDate as date) --assuming the clock in is always the same date as the start date
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that records in lookup dates and data do not spread over several days, you can join on the day. The rest is just a series of `case` expressions and a little date arithmetics:

```
select
    d.EmpId,
    d.StartDate,
    l.ClockInDate,
    case when d.StartDate < l.ClockInDate 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end IsClockInBefore,
    case when d.StartDate < l.ClockInDate 
        then datediff(second, ClockInDate, StartDate) 
        else 0 
    end ClockInBeforeTimeInSec,
    case when d.StartDate > l.ClockInDate 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end IsClockInAfter,
    case when d.StartDate > l.ClockInDate 
        then datediff(second, StartDate, ClockInDate) 
        else 0 
    end ClockInAfterTimeInSec,
    d.EndDate,
    l.ClockOutDate,
    case when d.EndDate < l.ClockOutDate 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end IsClockOutBefore,
    case when d.EndDate < l.ClockOutDate 
        then datediff(second, ClockOutDate, StartDate) 
        else 0 
    end ClockOutBeforeTimeInSec,
    case when d.EndDate > l.ClockOutDate 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end IsClockOutAfter,
    case when d.EndDate > l.ClockOutDate 
        then datediff(second, StartDate, ClockOutDate) 
        else 0 
    end ClockOutAfterTimeInSec
from #Data d
inner join #LookupDates l 
    on cast(d.ClockInDate as date) = cast(l.StartDate as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a different method.
Just tried a few different things.
*(Okay, I admit. I was really bored.)*

> ```
> SELECT
>  io.EmpId,
>  lk.StartDate AS LookupStartDate,
>  io.ClockInDate,
>  CAST(  IIF(io.ClockInDate < lk.StartDate,1,0) AS BIT) AS IsClockInBefore,
>  (CASE WHEN io.ClockInDate < lk.StartDate
>   THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, io.ClockInDate, lk.StartDate) 
>   ELSE 0 END) AS ClockInBeforeTimeInSec,
>  CAST(  IIF(io.ClockInDate > lk.StartDate, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS IsClockInAfter,
>  (CASE WHEN io.ClockInDate > lk.StartDate
>   THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, lk.StartDate, io.ClockInDate) 
>   ELSE 0 END) AS ClockInAfterTimeInSec,
>  lk.EndDate AS LookupEndDate,
>  io.ClockOutDate,
>  CAST(  IIF(io.ClockOutDate < lk.EndDate,1,0) AS BIT) AS IsClockOutBefore,
>  (CASE WHEN io.ClockOutDate < lk.EndDate
>   THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, io.ClockOutDate, lk.EndDate) 
>   ELSE 0 END) AS ClockOutBeforeTimeInSec,
>  CAST(  IIF(io.ClockOutDate > lk.EndDate,1,0) AS BIT) AS IsClockOutAfter,
>  (CASE WHEN io.ClockOutDate > lk.EndDate
>   THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, lk.EndDate, io.ClockOutDate) 
>   ELSE 0 END) AS ClockOutAfterTimeInSec
> FROM #Data AS io
> JOIN #LookupDates AS lk
>   ON CONVERT(DATE, lk.StartDate) = CONVERT(DATE, io.ClockInDate)
> ORDER BY io.EmpId, io.ClockInDate;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EmpId | LookupStartDate     | ClockInDate         | IsClockInBefore | ClockInBeforeTimeInSec | IsClockInAfter | ClockInAfterTimeInSec | LookupEndDate       | ClockOutDate        | IsClockOutBefore | ClockOutBeforeTimeInSec | IsClockOutAfter | ClockOutAfterTimeInSec
> ----: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :-------------- | ---------------------: | :------------- | --------------------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :--------------- | ----------------------: | :-------------- | ---------------------:
>     1 | 01/12/2019 08:00:00 | 01/12/2019 07:00:00 | True            |                   3600 | False          |                     0 | 01/12/2019 16:00:00 | 01/12/2019 07:30:00 | True             |                   30600 | False           |                      0
>     1 | 01/12/2019 08:00:00 | 01/12/2019 18:00:00 | False           |                      0 | True           |                 36000 | 01/12/2019 16:00:00 | 01/12/2019 22:00:00 | False            |                       0 | True            |                  21600
>     1 | 02/12/2019 10:00:00 | 02/12/2019 09:30:00 | True            |                   1800 | False          |                     0 | 02/12/2019 18:00:00 | 02/12/2019 18:00:00 | False            |                       0 | False           |                      0
>     1 | 03/12/2019 08:30:00 | 03/12/2019 09:00:00 | False           |                      0 | True           |                  1800 | 03/12/2019 16:30:00 | 03/12/2019 16:30:00 | False            |                       0 | False           |                      0
>     1 | 04/12/2019 08:00:00 | 04/12/2019 08:00:00 | False           |                      0 | False          |                     0 | 04/12/2019 16:00:00 | 04/12/2019 15:45:00 | True             |                     900 | False           |                      0
>     1 | 05/12/2019 08:00:00 | 05/12/2019 08:00:00 | False           |                      0 | False          |                     0 | 05/12/2019 16:00:00 | 05/12/2019 17:15:00 | False            |                       0 | True            |                   4500
>     1 | 06/12/2019 09:00:00 | 06/12/2019 08:40:00 | True            |                   1200 | False          |                     0 | 06/12/2019 17:00:00 | 06/12/2019 16:45:00 | True             |                     900 | False           |                      0
>     1 | 07/12/2019 08:30:00 | 07/12/2019 08:25:00 | True            |                    300 | False          |                     0 | 07/12/2019 16:30:00 | 07/12/2019 17:05:00 | False            |                       0 | True            |                   2100
>     1 | 08/12/2019 11:00:00 | 08/12/2019 12:00:00 | False           |                      0 | True           |                  3600 | 08/12/2019 15:30:00 | 08/12/2019 15:15:00 | True             |                     900 | False           |                      0
>     1 | 09/12/2019 08:30:00 | 09/12/2019 08:30:01 | False           |                      0 | True           |                     1 | 09/12/2019 16:30:00 | 09/12/2019 16:30:27 | False            |                       0 | True            |                     27
>     1 | 10/12/2019 10:30:00 | 10/12/2019 10:30:00 | False           |                      0 | False          |                     0 | 10/12/2019 16:45:00 | 10/12/2019 16:45:00 | False            |                       0 | False           |                      0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8f13a4032d65d298eebb8c1c40016672)*

Answer (score 1):

I guess all you need is multiple same case for different no of columns. Nothings there else in your query.

```
     Select case when 
    checkindatetime<estimated then
    1 else 0 end as "CheckedInearly" ,
    Abs(checkindatetime-estimated) 
   .....same logic for other columns
   From table
```